# Tarantula - ruby issue

Tags: ruby, rake, fedora, tarantula

I am trying to install Tarantula ( http://www.testiatarantula.com/ ) on Fedora (kernel 3.6.5-2.fc16.x86_64) using the documentation at (https://github.com/prove/tarantula) .

The issue I ran into is Ruby error (A) :

```
/opt/tarantula/config/initializers/session_store.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected ':', 
expecting $end ...sion_store :cookie_store, key: '_tarantula_session'
                                              ^

Tasks: TOP => db:schema:load => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

when executing the command :

```
 sudo RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake tarantula:install
```

The

```
 bundle exec
```

command is used to overcome another error (B):

```
sudo RAILS_ENV=production rake tarantula:install 
[sudo] password for admin: 
rake aborted!
You have already activated rake 10.0.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.9.2.2. Using   
bundle exec may solve this.
/opt/tarantula/config/boot.rb:6
/opt/tarantula/config/application.rb:1
/opt/tarantula/Rakefile:5
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Error (A) can be traced back to https://github.com/prove/tarantula/blob/master/config/initializers/session_store.rb .

Using

```
--trace
```

the outputs are:

```
sudo RAILS_ENV=production rake tarantula:install --trace
rake aborted!
You have already activated rake 10.0.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.9.2.2. Using bundle exec may solve this.
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in `setup'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:17:in `setup'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `require'
/opt/tarantula/config/boot.rb:6
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/opt/tarantula/config/application.rb:1
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/opt/tarantula/Rakefile:5
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:581:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:87:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:158:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:86:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:158:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/application.rb:68:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.2/bin/rake:37
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
```

Comment: Can you please paste your `session_store.rb` file?

Comment: A file link was provided, i.e https://github.com/prove/tarantula/blob/master/config/initializers/session_store.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try your `session_store.rb` with this line:

`Tarantula::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_tarantula_session'`

Whats the Ruby Version you are running? I'm doubting it's 1.8.7 ?

`ruby -v` for Ruby version.

**EDIT**

And `wrap_parameters.rb` with this on line 8:

```
wrap_parameters :format => [:json]
```

Comment: Now I am using an Ubuntu box (same issue). Output of `ruby -v` is `ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]`

Comment: Your `session_store.rb` specified hash syntax from Ruby 1.9.x (`key:`) which I changed to 1.8.7 compatible syntax (`:key =>`) in my answer above. I would personally upgrade my Ruby and give it a shot on 1.9.3.

Comment: also, can you make sure `bundle update` succeeds when run from the app root.?

Comment: I've tried this. For `RAILS_ENV=production rake tarantula:install` the issue persists. And, for `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake tarantula:install` the outcome is a new error `/opt/tarantula/rails/config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND
  wrap_parameters format: [:json]`

Comment: Your application is expecting Ruby 1.9.3 whereas you are trying to run it on 1.8.7. Upgrade your Ruby version. I'm including the change required to `wrap_parameters.rb` in my answer above - But probably a few other things might break in the app since it's expecting Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: The output of `bundle update` is `Your bundle is updated! Use bundle show [gemname] to see where a bundled gem is installed.`

Comment: The modification for `wrap_parameters.rb` solved the issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the version of rake to use in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rake', '=0.9.2.2'
```

and `bundle update`

Comment: I've changed the file as you said, `bundle update`, `bundle install --no-deployment`, fallowed by `RAILS_ENV=production rake tarantula:install`, but the issue remains.

Comment: Did you try `bundle exec RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake tarantula:install` ?

Comment: No, but the modification of `session_store.rb` and `wrap_parameters.rb` as recommended by @jasdeep-singh solved the issue.